# Wrong negative look behind expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to filter every string which are not valid (simple) email adress.
Thus starting with a dot is a "no go".

But my expression doesn't reject strings like `.test@test.be`

`preg_match('/^(?<!\.)[\w0-9\.]+(?<!\.)@+(?<!\.)[\w0-9\.]+\.\w{1,3}(\s*<[^>]+>)?$/', $part)`

Shouldn't `/^(?<!\.)` do the trick?

**EDIT:**
This question is not a duplicate of the indicated question.

I am not asking about the context, I want more information about look behind, the approach itself, not the specific use-case.

Comment: Have you looked at `filter_var()` with filter `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out its look-ahead counterpart (`^(?!\.)`) does the trick instead:
https://regex101.com/r/zZ8yT7/1

Comment: could it be that look behind expression are meant to be put at the end of something instead of in front of it?